# Merging two arrays with some logic in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to merge something like (I show it in json)

```
[["Field1","0"],["Field2","0"],["Field3","0"]]
```

with

```
{"0":{"Name":"Foo","Lastname":"Bar"}}
```

when I do

```
$.extend({}, firstArray, secondArray);
```

I get in JSON

```
{
 "0":{"Name":"Foo","Lastname":"Bar"},
 "1":["Field1","0"],
 "2":["Field2","0"]
}
```

as you can see the first array is some kind of mixed with the second. I want it to be wrapped up like this

```
{
"0":{"Name":"Foo","Lastname":"Bar"},
"1":[ "1": ["Field1","0"],"2":["Field2","0"]]
}
```

So later when I consume it I can get the field stuff as one array. Is the possible? I cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Your "1" key's value syntax is incorrect.  Is it supposed to be a new object or an array?

Comment: Why is Field3 missing? What's the logic behind that?

Comment: I think I don't get the question. We saw what you get but what do you expect. The jQuery docs says exactly what you get. Are you looking for  [["Field1","0"],["Field2","0"],["Field3","0"]].push({"0":{"Name":"Foo","Lastname":"Bar"}}); or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you only need to add `secondArray` as a property of `firstArray`, but converted into an object. That can be accomplished like this:

```
firstArray["1"] = $.extend({}, {}, secondArray);
```

Now `firstArray` becomes:

```
{
"0":{"Name":"Foo","Lastname":"Bar"},
"1":{"0": ["Field1","0"], "1":["Field2","0"]}
}
```

I hope that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

`firstarray = firstarray.concat(secondarray)`